# Azure Pipeline generate a .sln/.csproj as part of the pipeline process from a folder

Tags: unity-game-engine, azure-pipelines

Is there a way to generate a solution and project file out of a folder structure through a azure pipeline .ymal stage?

The way the project has been set up is that there are lots of other .git repos set up inside a master repo and inserted though subtrees. These repos don't have a .sln in themselves but instead when they are added into Unity they get added into the projects .sln and a .csproj is generated for each of the assemblies within the submodule (package)

What I'm looking to do is to have documentation generated for each of these submodules whenever an update is pushed to its master (not the projects it lives in master) as these tend to be more utilities and self contained systems. Problem I'm facing is that I can trigger all the documentation system with docFX but because this module does not contain a .csproj I'm unable to generate the documentation for it. so I'm wondering if its possible to have a step where I can create a project file for all scripts that are within a folder structure, and as such then have a project file for docFX to work of.

I know its not ideal in any sense, but wondering if its a possibility while I investigate further into other solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to generate a solution and project file out of a folder
> structure through a azure pipeline .ymal stage?

For this issue, I am afraid that azure pipeline is impossible to achieve this.

> ".csproj" is a Visual Studio .NET C# Project file extension. This file
> will have information about the files included in that project,
> assemblies used in that project, project GUID and project version etc.
> This file is related to your project. It will be **automatically**
> generated when we create
>
> ".sln" is a structure for organizing projects in Visual Studio. It
> contains the state information for projects in .sln (text-based,
> shared) and .suo (binary, user-specific solution options) files. We
> can add multiple projects inside one solution.

Azure pipeline cannot generate a solution and project file according to the folder structure.

Comment: Thanks for the help. My assumption from looking was that this was the case, but was wondering if maybe I had just missed something. Thanks for the confirmation will look into different solutions for the underlaying problem